# Heroku not allow me deploy the project as i follow the instruction but not work in my case

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

Here is my error, I also followed the instructions in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238241/heroku-build-failing-due-to-yarn-and-npm-lockfile-conflict)
But the same error occurs as I remove and commit the code on heroku master but same log occur thousands of times. I don't know where I am wrong. Here is my error log on cmd:

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:  !     Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock
remote:
remote:        Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
remote:        but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
remote:        dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
remote:        packages or subtle bugs in production.
remote:
remote:        - To use npm to install your application's dependencies please delete
remote:          the yarn.lock file.
remote:
remote:          $ git rm yarn.lock
remote:
remote:        - To use yarn to install your application's dependences please delete
remote:          the package-lock.json file.
remote:
remote:          $ git rm package-lock.json
remote:
remote:        https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-conflicting-lock-files
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to socialbites.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/dummyApp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

And my file tree is: 
[image]

Comment: Which directory are you pushing to heroku? client or the parent containing client?

Comment: Did U ever solve this? I have the same issue and cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have two "lock" files in your project, and Heroku only allows to have one to install the dependencies of your project.

**To fix this issue you can follow the next steps**

1. Open the project folder in the terminal and delete one of the "lock" files.

   > Remove the yarn.lock file if you are using npm or delete package-lock.json if you are using yarn to install the dependencies.

   ```
   $ git rm yarn.lock
   ```
2. Create a new commit to save the changes.

   ```
   $ git commit -m "delete yarn.lock"
   ```
3. Deploy the project.

   ```
   $ git push heroku master
   ```

Comment: this is  not working for me i already do these steps and there is no file such file "yarn.lock" in my project directory

Comment: ok, try to initialize a new local repo and copy / paste the project files into the new repo, then create a commit and configure the git remote url of heroku to deploy the app again.
It is not a good solution but it could help you.

Comment: @HamzaMazhar, are you seeing the same error message after removing `yarn.lock`, or a different one? It looks like you have now removed _both_ lockfiles. You need one of them.

Comment: same error message i just removed yarn.lock not keep the other(package-lock)file