# Heroku deployment fails over yarn.lock file that doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm, yarnpkg

I keep getting the "Two different lockfiles found" error when trying to deploy to Heroku

```
remote: Building source:
remote:  !     Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock
remote:        Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
remote:        but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
remote:        dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
remote:        packages or subtle bugs in production.
```

I've found a few threads on here that have the same issue except...
I don't have a yarn.lock file to remove.

If I run the commands suggested in this thread:[Heroku build failing due to Yarn and npm lockfile conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238241/heroku-build-failing-due-to-yarn-and-npm-lockfile-conflict), I just get a message saying there isn't a file to remove. I'm checking the repo and my files in vsCode and i don't see a `yarn.lock` file so why does Heroku think I have a yarn.lock file?

SOLUTION: I found out that I had configured the heroku project to auto deploy based on my commits to the repo on Github. I guess the error message I was receiving wast he only one that applied when I was trying to manually push to heroku and i wasn't supposed to. If you run into this check you heroku settings, if you have auto deploy this situation may come up.

Comment: Could you go to your project root directory and execute the command `ls -a`? Still no `yarn.lock` file? Are you sure the `yarn.lock` file is removed in the remote repository?

Comment: I checked both with ls -a and theres still not yarn.lock. Not sure what else I can do

Comment: Have you tried running ls -a through the Heroku CLI? It's possible that your app instance on Heroku has a yarn.lock file. Example: "heroku run bash --app your-app-name". After bash mounts, try typing ls -a, and see if you have both package.lock and yarn.lock.

Comment: The error message was a but misleading, but i found out what my problem was. my deployment settings were set to automatic

Answer (score 0):

Just in case... when you type `git push heroku master` be sure you're master Branch doesn't have two lockfiles in it. If you are a on another Branch just try `git push heroku <your branch name you want to push>`